# Partially update a complex object in Entity Framework Core in a web api

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I'm having issues trying to update a rather complex object in an ASP.NET Core Web API.

I changed my put method to the following code:

```
    [Authorize(Policy = "IsAuthor")]
    [HttpPut("{id}")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> PutCIApplication([FromRoute] Guid id, [FromBody] CIApplication cIApplication)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return BadRequest(ModelState);
        }

        if (id != cIApplication.ID)
        {
            return BadRequest();
        }

        string userLang = HttpContext.Request.Headers["UserCulture"].ToString();

        cIApplication.Translations[userLang].Name = cIApplication.Name;
        cIApplication.Translations[userLang].Description = cIApplication.Description;

        var dbCIApplication = await _context.CIApplications.Include(c => c.Translations)
                        .Include(c => c.DeploymentScenarios).ThenInclude(d => d.InstallSequence).ThenInclude(s => s.Steps).ThenInclude(s => s.SubSteps)
                        .Include(c => c.DeploymentScenarios).ThenInclude(d => d.UninstallSequence).ThenInclude(s => s.Steps).ThenInclude(s => s.SubSteps)
                        .Include(c => c.SoftwareMeteringRules).Include(c => c.Catalogs).Include(c => c.Categories)
                        .AsNoTracking()
                        .SingleOrDefaultAsync(m => m.ID == id);

        HashSet<string> excludedProperties = new HashSet<string>();
        excludedProperties.Add("OwnerCompanyID");
        excludedProperties.Add("OwnerCompany");
        excludedProperties.Add("CreatedDate");
        excludedProperties.Add("CreatedBy");
        excludedProperties.Add("UpdatedDate");
        excludedProperties.Add("UpdatedBy");

        var patch = JsonPatchCreation.CreatePatch(dbCIApplication, cIApplication, excludedProperties);

        if ((await _authorizationService.AuthorizeAsync(User, cIApplication, "CIAuthoringManagement")).Succeeded)
        {
            patch.ApplyTo(dbCIApplication);

            try
            {
                await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
            }
            catch (DbUpdateConcurrencyException)
            {
                if (!CIApplicationExists(id))
                {
                    return NotFound();
                }
                else
                {
                    throw;
                }
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                throw;
            }

            return NoContent();
        }
        else
        {
            return Unauthorized();
        }
 }
```

As you can see, the `CIApplication` class contains lots of relationships with other classes and dependent themselves have a lot of relations.

This controller action works fine with a simple object which doesn't have any relations.

But in this case, the controller doesn't throw any exception, but the object isn't updated in database.

I first tried without the `.AsNoTracking`, but in this case I have an exception saying that a `DeploymentScenarios` is already tracked.

I want to do a partial update because some relations aren't sent to my native client by the get action (in this case `OwnerCompany`) and so when the object is sent for update the navigation property have a null value and thus EF Core removes the relation.

If someone have an idea on how to make it work in the most simplest way it would be great !

Thanks !

Comment: First of all I'd place it in a try/catch block, Write a unit test for it and Build it up slowly, this will help you pinpoint which include it doesn't like. Also as a rule, all of this should not be in the controller. some should be pushed back into the service layer and the context savechanges should be right back in your repository layer.